# Visualforce Form auto submit

Tags: visualforce

I am creating a form in Visualforce.  I am passing in parameters through the URL to fill in the fields.  I would like for this form to auto-submit to trigger the Apex controller.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a visual form at all? If the purpose of the form is simply to take some query parameters and do something with them, why not simply have your page be

```
<apex:page action="{!myCustomSubmit}">
```

Then in the controller your method

```
public PageReference myCustomSubmit()
{
//Read your query parameters and do stuff
PageReference pRef = //Where do you want to go after you've done your custom work?
return pRef; 
}
```

This may be what Amr Ibrahim was getting at, but I couldn't comment on that post so I created a net new answer.

Comment: Just confirming, the controller can pull the parameters out of the url and use them to update a record (ie case)?

Comment: Yes, no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to trigger the controller on page load, you can always use action attribute in the page. This will be like

Reference https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm